# how to disable select tag hover effect?

Tags: html, css

I have this code :

```
<select name="color" selected="selected" id="color"  style="width:100px;">
<option>colors</option>
```

php :-

```
    if(isset( $_GET['size']) ) {
  $size = $_GET['size'];
  }

  $query = "SELECT color FROM product_attr WHERE size='".$size."' AND `quantity`!='0'"; 
  $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

      echo "<option style='background-color:$query_row[0]' value ='".$query_row[0]."'></option> ";
      }
```

it works fine and i get every `<option>` with its color as a background but the only issue is that the hover effect of the mouse on the `<option>` makes the colors looking bad kinda and i don't know how to remove it! any suggestions? thanks in advance

Comment: Don't know if this will work `option:hover{background-color: transparent}`

Comment: it is not working dear

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
option {
    background:transparent; 
}
```

in your CSS